# Multiple manifests for the application

Tags: android

Can one Android app have multiple manifests? For example, one for the development stage and the other for production.

If so, how can this be implemented?

Comment: Use productFlavours in gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use productFlavours in gradle.

```
productFlavors {
        prdo{
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Sample APP'
            resValue 'string', 'base_url', 'http://sampleapp.com/'
        }
        staging{
            resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'Sample APP Staging'
            resValue 'string', 'base_url', 'http://sampleapp.staging.com/'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your APK file can contain just one AndroidManifest.xml file**

When building your app, the Gradle build merges all manifest files into a single manifest file that's packaged into your APK.

Look at from the android official site:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: this is not what he is asking about

Answer (score 2):

Use source set `main` and `debug` and put two `AndroidManifest.xml` into there. `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` will be merged for debug builds; it only has changes and/or eg. additional activities (one can also add code into that source set).